# Will engraving the back of my Galaxy S8 interfere with the waterproof-ness?

Tags: hardware, samsung-galaxy-s-8

I am thinking about laser-engraving a large logo on on the back of my Galaxy S8. The image I have in mind is about 40x40mm and will be centered vertically between the *SAMSUNG* and the lower *CE* and IMEI markings, and centered horizontally.

Will this in any way break the ability to withstand water, like when I wipe the phone with a wet cloth or when it gets rained on?

I am aware that this will obviously void the warranty, and that there is a risk of breaking the device.

Comment: This might be off-topic. I didn't see a tag for external modifications, but I think this Stack Exchange is the one best suited for my question.

Comment: Off-topic quite certainly. As for the question itself, the only problem I can think of is the glass breaking from where you engraved under high pressure, but I don't think the phone is built to withstand water with that depth/pressure in the first place.

Comment: I don't see why this would be off-topic. I think it's a really interesting question and a welcome change from the sea of "I broke my phone" questions.

Comment: @DanHulme well, this is more of a physics/material engineering question than an Android question...

Comment: @DanHulme it is a question of deliberately planning on breaking my phone in a controlled way.